# Node js clusters can't be imported in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm imported clusters as
`import * as cluster from "cluster";`
and when I'm trying to check `cluster.isMaster` in `if(cluster.isMaster){}` I'm getting this error

```
TS2339: Property 'isMaster' does not exist on type 'typeof import("cluster")'.
```

and
`import cluster from "cluster";` 
I'm getting that cluster is `undefined`.
How can I solve the problem in ts, how can I import clusters in ts and use them?

Comment: You can add the type definitions of standard node imports by installing the npm package `@types/node` so that it will work with TypeScript. If the issue is only occurring in TS.

Comment: it didn't work, @types/node has already installed.

Comment: It seems like the module `cluster` doesn't export `isMaster`

Comment: And how can I use it in typescript?

Comment: You can't import something that's not exported. I don't know module `cluster` so I don't know how to use `isMaster`.

Comment: At the time of writing this, the type definitions for the `cluster` module are incompatible with certain combinations of source and target module formats. A [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59058) is available to address some of these gaps whose types you might be able to use directly in your project.

Answer (score 10):

I have got the same issue today, and this workaround worked for me:

```
import * as _cluster from 'cluster';
const cluster = _cluster as unknown as _cluster.Cluster; // typings fix
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today and solved it by setting `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Install `@types/node` as dev dependency

> npm install @types/node --save-dev

Sample Code:

```
import cluster from 'cluster'
import { cpus } from 'os'

import App from "./App"
import config from "./config/config"


const app = new App().express
const port = config.port

if (cluster.isPrimary === true) { 
    // .isPrimary with node v16.0.0 or above
    // .isMaster (depreciated) with older version
    const CPUS: any = cpus()
    CPUS.forEach(() => cluster.fork())
} else {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`API is listening on http://localhost:${port} on ${process.pid}`);
    });
}
```

You need to import the `cluster` constant that is exported by default in the file

> /node_modules/@types/node/cluster.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

`isMaster` is not a named import of the the `cluster` module. It's a property of the default export of the module.

This means that you want to import the default export, and not as `import * as`.

```
import cluster from "cluster"
if (cluster.isMaster) { console.log('master') }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYFcDOMCmU4DMoQhwBEy6WUxAUFcLnABRkbYB0waAsgIYtQCUcAN6IIAOzQQkmVkggBzBgHIQvCksEBfIA)

Comment: but this way also didn't work too. If I am imported as
import cluster from 'cluster'
I am getting cluster is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The right way to import it is:

```
import cluster from 'node:cluster';
```

At least it's the way suggested by the official docs for latest versions of NodeJS, check out an example at https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#clusterworker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing this issue to import cluster module in typescript.

We can import it as below which works with commonJS module resolution

```
import * as cluster from "cluster";
const thisCluster = (cluster as any) as cluster.Cluster;
```